# java regex - displaying multiple line

Tags: java, regex, delphi

I'm trying to create a Lexical Analyzer for Delphi. I'm currently in the part of displaying a multiple line comment which I can't somehow.

This is my regex:

```
    String multiComm="\\{[^\\}]*\\}";
```

And this is my condition to display it:

```
       matcher=Pattern.compile(multiComm).matcher(line); 
       if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("multiLn_comment"+"\t"+matcher.group());
       }
```

It can display a single line comment that starts with { and ends with } but cannot display multiple line comments. I've tested this regex in [this site](https://regex101.com/r/NK3s1Q/1) and it can read multiple line comments like:

```
{
  hello
}
```

Here's the full procedure of the code:

```
static void results()throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try {
    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String lineText = null;
    System.out.println("Token"+"\t\t"+"Lexeme");
    while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
    parseLine(lineText);
        }
        lineReader.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
private static void parseLine(String line)
    String multiComm="\\{[^\\}]*\\}";
    Matcher matcher = null;
       matcher=Pattern.compile(multiComm).matcher(line); 
       if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("multiLn_comment"+"\t"+matcher.group());
       }
```

Comment: Pro-tip: if you're gonna link regex101 site, you should better create the custom link with your actual regex setup on it

Comment: How do you expect the regex to find anything **multi-line** when you only give it one `line` at a time? I am of course assuming that variable named `line` is exact that, i.e. one line of text, otherwise it's rather misnamed.

Comment: @Victoria's answer worked fwiw .  I checked the link provided: https://regex101.com/r/KZpfhO/2 . It was probably deleted the because it had been down-voted, but I think it should be chosen as the correct answer.

Comment: @Jeff It's the same regex as with mine.

Comment: quSci, you cannot match multiline comment for single line that you read. Besides, it's more complex than your proposal (consider e.g. what is not `{}` multiline comment `//{`, or `S := '{}';`). @Jeff, downvote was not the reason (backslash needs to be escaped in Java string, so I've posted the same pattern as used in the above code).

Comment: Read the whole file inside a String variable to be able to use the same pattern, or use more sophisticated logic to grab matches starting on one line and extending to the subsequent line(s).